# VS Code on Mac: Error + Getting Started

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, dnx

I installed VS Code on my Mac, and used [this guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-app-using-vscode/) to attempt to get started. Everything was smooth until I tried to open the sample project by using ". code" in the console. Since the command was suppose to simply open the sample project, I attempted to skip that step, and open it myself. However, when I try to run the project using "dnx : Run Command", VS Code returns the following error:

> Error: This socket has been ended by the other party.

The guide suggests running it again and the socket should open, but it remains closed. Any suggestions on fixing this would be welcome. If you don't have suggestions to fix my current issue, I'm open to other VS Code setup tutorials for C#/VS Code on Macs!